# Error 403 User not authorized when trying to access Azure Databricks API through Active Directory

Tags: azure, oauth-2.0, azure-active-directory, azure-databricks

I have been following the document: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/dev-tools/api/latest/aad/service-prin-aad-token

to create a service principal and use it to access Databricks. I already have a databricks workspace configured and have used it to create a cluster. Then I've followed the process mentioned in the document, created a service principal and obtained the two tokens: AD Access token and management access token. However, I am unable to use the API.

The final call cURL command after configuration:

```
curl -X GET \
-H 'Authorization: Bearer <access-token>' \
-H 'X-Databricks-Azure-SP-Management-Token: <management-access-token>' \
-H 'X-Databricks-Azure-Workspace-Resource-Id: /subscriptions/<subscription-id>/resourceGroups/<resource-group-name>/providers/Microsoft.Databricks/workspaces/<workspace-name>' \
https://<databricks-instance>/api/2.0/clusters/list
```

With the tokens and the other info substitutued provides the following result:

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8"/>
<title>Error 403 User not authorized.</title>
</head>
<body><h2>HTTP ERROR 403</h2>
<p>Problem accessing /api/2.0/clusters/list. Reason:
<pre>    User not authorized.</pre></p>
</body>
</html>
```

I have tried a couple of things to resolve this, namely changing the original access token request to use the interactive flow using the `authorization_code` grant type and so on, but that just gives me an `Invalid access token` error.

Is there something wrong with the above configuration? Am I missing some permissions?

Update: Came to the Access control (IAM) page and the app does not seem to be included there.

Comment: Are you either a Contributor or Owner role on the Databricks workspace resource in Azure ?

Comment: The service principal must be added to the workspace either as part of the admin user login or using the Add service principal endpoint.

Comment: @Axel I am a contributor but despite that I was not able to provide access. Have requested access from my admin separately.

Comment: @CarlZhao Will obtain access and try this out.

Comment: If my answer is helpful for you, you can accept it as answer( click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.). See https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You must grant a role to the **service principal**.

This is the result of my test that I did not grant a role to the service principal. The error is the same as yours:

[image]

Next, grant roles to the service principal according to the following process:

**Azure Portal**>**Azure Databricks**>**Azure Databricks Service**>**Access control (IAM)>Add a role assignment**>**Select the role you want to grant and find your service principal**>**save**

[image]

Finally, use the service principal to get the token.(Don’t forget to grant permissions to service principals and grant administrator consent)

[image]
[image]

Get an Azure Active Directory access token:
[image]
Get the Azure Management Resource endpoint token:
[image]
Use the management endpoint access token to access the Databricks REST API:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

In case you wish to access the Databricks endpoints with just the access token, as is the case with using DBX in CI/CD workflows to trigger the Databricks pipelines, you would need to add the service principal as a user in the Databricks workspace. So then only the access token would be needed.

Refer to the documentation here- [Add Service Principal as Databricks user](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/dev-tools/api/latest/aad/service-prin-aad-token#get-token-azure-cli)