# Azure Databricks PAT token access to data - lost access

Tags: azure, api, token, databricks

This was working fine until now and may be related to the addition of suffix to the email accounts used to login to Azure since that's the only change in the environment.

We have an API that connects to Databricks using a PAT token, this is erroring out now.

Anyway, after recreating the PAT token using the SP account that has all the permissions, we get this "HTTP Protocol Error, 403 forbidden".

Checked out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63686132/error-403-user-not-authorized-when-trying-to-access-azure-databricks-api-through) posting which confirms the setting on the AAD side and DBXS side are correct .

Hope this is enough information to jog someones memory.

Thanks!